# famous is to infamous as impressive is to what?

Tags: word-request, analogy

I'm looking for the word that would describe something that's impressive but in a negative way. At first I was thinking "ridiculous" but it doesn't necessarily invite ridicule.

Comment: If you accept that ***impressive = sublime***, perhaps the contrast you're looking for is best encapsulated by the standard expression [*from the **sublime** to the ridiculous.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+sublime+to+the+ridiculous%22) Latterly, I've often seen ***from hero to zero***.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I was going to go with **unimpressive**... and then I realized it's more of a negation, not an opposite.  (If impressive is a positive, unimpressive is more of a zero than a negative.)

Comment: This is actually really hard.  The closest I can get is something like "monstrous", particularly with the nuance of a *monstrosity*.

Comment: So, to clarify, you want a word that one might define as "evoking admiration, awe, or respect (and so on) for being <some negative state>"? Or do you want something that one might define as "well-known for being <some negative state>"? The former implies that potential to be admirable to some in the way that some people admire gangsters, while the latter has a sense of "this is bad, just stay away".

Answer (score 5):

This is a really challenging analogy.  Infamous isn't the opposite of famous, but rather it means "famous for bad deeds or wickedness".  So we're looking for a word that means "impressive, but for something bad".

The closest I can get is "monstrous", particularly with the nuance of a "monstrosity".  For example, an enormous building that has impressively *awful* architecture, like what many think about the ["Walkie Talkie Tower" in London](https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/architecture-design-blog/2015/sep/02/walkie-talkie-london-wins-carbuncle-cup-worst-building-of-year)

Other possibilities:  grotesque, egregious, freakish, outrageous.

Comment: What about _aghast_, _appalling_, _awful_ and _uncomely_?

Comment: @OmkarReddy *aghast* doesn't fit in with those other words at all

Comment: @D.Nelson OK. What about the rest?

Comment: @OmkarReddy They could conceivably be used as synonyms for "monstrous" or "grotesque", yes.

Answer (score 1):

If fear is part of the reason for negativity then perhaps,

**Terrifying**

> 1. causing terror or apprehension
> 2. of a formidable nature

If something causes terror, it makes a distinctly negative impression, although negative in a specific way.

Answer (score 0):

If

> impressive

is *something* which stands out from the rest

These do not stand out

> normal
>   ordinary
>   everyday
>   regular
>
> The snowfall last night was *impressive*.
>   *It's* ***normal*** *for this time of year.*
>
> The driving skills of cabbies in Mumbai is *impressive*.
>   *It's quite* ***ordinary***, *they do it all the time.*
>
> The rush hour traffic in LA is quite *impressive*.
>   *Not really, it happens* ***everyday***.

To get a negative, usually more than one word is necessary

> impressively bad
>   exceedingly bad

and the context of what is meant by "bad" needs to be clarified.

Answer (score -4):

A quick Google Search led to these:

- dull
- underwhelming
- undistinguished
- disappointing
- unexciting
- uninteresting

Hope these help.

Comment: None of these seem like accurate analogies.  Infamous doesn't mean "not famous", it means "famous for bad deeds".   So we're looking for a word that means something like "impressive but evil".